# Download a shared xlsx from sharepoint via "shared link" using Node.JS

Tags: node.js, fetch-api

Seems easy but been stuck on this for days.

Here is a shared link to a sample Excel file in my Sharepoint: `https://netorgft7979143-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/gabe_scoop_report/EQA2ZBArOjZEuoTUfZ_smSIBQpRvlImIRfiTXg8742fwfw?download=1`. Anyone can hit it and your browser will download the file.

I am trying to write Node.js code to hit this URL and download the file for me and save on disk.  Should be easy, right?

I tried using Puppeteer to emulate how a browser would do it, and my code is like this:

```
    const buffer = await page.evaluate(({downloadURL}) =>
    {
      return fetch('https://netorgft7979143-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/gabe_scoop_report/EQA2ZBArOjZEuoTUfZ_smSIBQpRvlImIRfiTXg8742fwfw?download=1', {
        method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
                'Accept-Encoding': '',
                binaryStringResponseBody: true
            },
        encoding: null
      })
       .then(response => response.text())
```

So here's the deal: using this code to hit a sharepoint file that's plain text (e.g. CSV file), it works perfectly.  But in the present example, with .xlsx being the file targetted, what we get back is some funky misalignment of bytes so the resulting xlsx is corrupt (as if the code above recognizes .xlsx is binary/gzip and tries to do something funky with it as it's downloading)

If you download the .xlsx directly by hitting the URL with your browser, you get something like this: `504b 0304 0a00 0000 0800 0000 2100 1f9b 5d8b ef00 0000 8a01 0000 1000 0000 646f 6350 726f 7073 2f61 7070 2e78 6d6c 9c90...`

Using the code above, you get something similar but somehow different: `504b 0304 0a00 0000 0800 0000 2100 1fef bfbd 5def bfbd efbf bd00 0000 efbf bd01...`

Does anyone have any idea how to fix the issue--or maybe even an easier way altogether to hit that URL and save the downloaded file to disk?

THx!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting buffer you need to convert that into file try it with fileStream.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

 const url = 'www.example.com/image.png'; // link to file you want to download
const path = 'app/assets/my_image_name.xlsx' // where to save a file

const request = http.get(url, function(response) {
    if (response.statusCode === 200) {
        var file = fs.createWriteStream(path);
        response.pipe(file);
    }
    request.setTimeout(60000, function() { // if after 60s file not downlaoded, we abort a request 
        request.abort();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but not quite there.  The output is "304 Forbidden" (tho if you hit the URL I gave directly, the file downloads with no issues). So my guess is that it's an issue w cookies+redirects?

Comment: Wait for sometime before redirecting you can use setTimeout